# NSPredicate does not return the expected items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to find an items in the array where `itemId` and `size` are not matched.
However, the following query does not return me item(s) where `itemId` same but `size` different. I wonder what I am missing.

First I am extracting the item as follows, then I am trying to find compliment of this item.

```
NSPredicate *itemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", kItemId, itemId];
NSPredicate *sizePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", kSize, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", size]];
NSPredicate *combinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[itemPredicate, sizePredicate]];
NSArray *itemInOrder = [sharedData.orderItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:combinedPredicate];
```

Trying to extract **complimentary** items of `itemInOrder`

```
NSPredicate *restOfOrderPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K != %@)", kItemId, itemId];
NSPredicate *restSizePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K != %@)", kSize, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", size]];
NSPredicate *restCombinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[restSizePredicate, sizePredicate]];
NSMutableArray *restOfItemsInOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sharedData.orderItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:restOfOrderPredicate]];
```

Comment: Can you try this  NSPredicate *itemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K ==[c] %@)", kItemId, itemId];

Comment: I want to find items where `itemId` and `size` **together** are not in the array. In other words, complement of the `itemInOrder`

Comment: can u store them with dummy text in empty state and compare to it

Comment: Could you please illustrate you comment with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 issues here:

1. Your complementary `and` predicate is using the `sizePredicate`, but I think you want to be using `restSizePredicate`.
2. I think you want to use an `or` predicate.  As you have it now, you'll miss anything that has just the same size or just the same `itemId`.

An alternate approach could be to use a fetch that gets all the objects.  Then use your existing fetch to get the original set you wanted.  Then use Set Arithmetic to remove the second set from the first.

** EDIT **

3. I just now discovered `notPredicateWithSubpredicate` which is probably exactly what you want: Keep your first query and predicate as is.  Then for the second query, use `notPredicateWithSubpredicate` and pass in your predicate from the first query.

Comment: could you please illustrate with an example?